# If and when to close the database when using commonsware loaderex SQLiteCursorLoader?

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor, commonsware-cwac

Do I need to be concerned about making sure the database is closed when a FragmentActivity that uses a LoaderEx SQLiteCursorLoader is paused or destroyed?
Thanks much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the `FragmentActivity` is destroyed, it should call `reset()` on all `Loader` instances it created, which will call `onReset()` in the `Loader` implementation, which in `SQLiteCursorLoader` calls `close()` on any outstanding `Cursor`.

Note that this happens when the activity is destroyed. There does not seem to be a `Loader` equivalent of the managed `Cursor` concept of deactivating the `Cursor` when the activity is paused. That's a pity, as that was a nice heap management feature, and I'll ponder how to best support that.

If you find evidence that something is being leaked, [file an issue in the LoaderEx project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-loaderex/issues) with details of how to reproduce the error.

Comment: +1, but if I understood correctly, one of the claimed advantages of `Loader` is that data (`Cursor` in this case) is retained after the `Activity` is destroyed - for example on configuration change. This is possible because the `LoaderManager` life is decoupled from the `Activity` one and may span over (please, correct me if I'm wrong). But this no longer stands if we close everything `onDestroy()`. Why not using a plain `AsyncTask` then? How can one keep track of all of the created `Loader`s? And what about closing the `SQLiteOpenHelper`? That's important, too

Comment: @Raffaele: `FragmentActivity` (and the baseline `Activity` of API Level 11+), have the smarts to deal with configuration changes properly. In this answer, when I wrote "is destroyed", I really meant "is destroyed for the final time, not due to a configuration change". I apologize for any confusion.

Comment: And what's the callback associated with this *real destruction*? One needs it to close loaders. One also needs to ensure that when this happens there's no `Loader` running. Moreover, the `LoaderManager` API doesn't list the init'ed `Loader`'s, so one must keep track of them by hand, or just init and closing every possible loader, but this approach is feasible only for *fixed* loaders, and can't support *loaders on demand*

Comment: @Raffaele: "One needs it to close loaders" -- `FragmentActivity` "closes" loaders (via a call to `reset()`), as I mentioned in the opening paragraph of the answer to which you are commenting. "One also needs to ensure that when this happens there's no Loader running" -- or, just let the `AsyncTask` inside the loader run to completion, since that will only take a moment anyway in man cases. If you have further questions regarding the `Loader` framework, please read the source code -- the Android Support package's code may already be on your hard drive.